# Passing events between threads run from separate class C#

Tags: c#, events

I'm struggling to pass data between a thread started in a separate class from my main form. I believe (I could be wrong) that I should use an event. The problem I have is my subscribers are always null as I call the BluetoothScan class and start the thread before the event is subscribed to:

```
BluetoothScan bluetoothScan = new BluetoothScan(this);            
bluetoothScan.BluetoothDeviceDiscovered += OnBluetoothDeviceDiscovered;
```

How do I subscribe to the event before starting the thread?

I have my Main Form:

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Invoke_System_Delegate_System_Object___


namespace YieldMonitor
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            
        }

        private void BtnConnectBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Start looking for the yield monitor device.
            
            BluetoothScan bluetoothScan = new BluetoothScan(this);            
            bluetoothScan.BluetoothDeviceDiscovered += OnBluetoothDeviceDiscovered;
        }

        static void OnBluetoothDeviceDiscovered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message recieved from event");
        }

    }

}
```

My class that looks for bluetooth devices and if the right one is found should fire the event:

```
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace YieldMonitor
{
    class BluetoothScan
    {

        public event EventHandler BluetoothDeviceDiscovered;

        public BluetoothScan(MainForm mainForm)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting BluetoothScan Class");
            Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running BluetoothScan Class");

            string myDeviceName;
            ulong myDeviceAddress;

            BluetoothClient btClient = new BluetoothClient();
            BluetoothDeviceInfo[] btDevices = btClient.DiscoverDevices().ToArray();
            foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in btDevices)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d.DeviceName);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d.DeviceAddress);

                //have we found the device we are looking for?
                if (d.DeviceName == "DSD TECH HC-05")
                {
                    myDeviceName = d.DeviceName;
                    myDeviceAddress = d.DeviceAddress;
                    //Send out found adapter to the next stage
                    OnBluetoothScanned(EventArgs.Empty);
                    break;

                }
            }                      
        }

        protected virtual void OnBluetoothScanned(EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running OnBlueToothScanned");

            EventHandler handler = BluetoothDeviceDiscovered;

            if (handler != null)// we have a subscriber to our event
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BluetoothScanned is Not empty");
                handler(this, e);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BluetoothScanned is Empty");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT

I've found some nice solutions using Tasks where I need to update a label once a task is completed ie.

```
bool myDevicePaired = false;
var eventDevicePaired = new Progress<bool>(boDevicePaired => myDevicePaired = boDevicePaired);
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BluetoothPair.Run(myDeviceAddress, eventDevicePaired), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

//Register the device is paired with the UI
if (myDevicePaired)
{
    BtnConnectBT.Text = "Disconnect?";
}
```

Which is working well for Tasks that have an end that I am waiting for example waiting for a bluetooth device to connect.

But I'm beginning to pull my hair out with ***System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'tbInfo' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'*** error when trying to update a form text box.

Example:

in my MainForm Class:

I create what I've called an Event Reciever...

```
private void BluetoothSocketEventReciever(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Debug.WriteLine("Event!!!"); //writes data to debug fine
        tbInfo.AppendText("Event!!!!"); //causing error
}
```

I create a task to read from the device...

```
private void ReadDataFromDevice(UInt64 myDeviceAddress)
{
         BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = new BluetoothSocket(myDeviceAddress);
         bluetoothSocket.BluetoothDataRecieved += BluetoothSocketEventReciever;

         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bluetoothSocket.Run(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

In my BluetoothSocket class I have an endless while loop which will be reading data from a socket (hopefully) At the moment its just creating an empty EventArgs to trigger the Event every second:

```
namespace YieldMonitor
{
    class BluetoothSocket
    {
        ulong myDeviceAddress;
        public event EventHandler BluetoothDataRecieved;

        public BluetoothSocket (ulong deviceAddress)
        {
            myDeviceAddress = deviceAddress;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Were in BluetoothSocket ... Address: " + myDeviceAddress);
            
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Debug.WriteLine("In BluetoothSocket - Address = " + myDeviceAddress);
                OnBluetoothDataRecieved(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnBluetoothDataRecieved(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = BluetoothDataRecieved;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            } else
            {
                //No subscribers
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but how can I pass the data from the endless loop to the text box on the main form?

EDIT

Think I've just sorted it.

```
private void BluetoothSocketEventReciever(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Event!!!");
            tbInfo.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                tbInfo.AppendText("Event!!!");
            });


           //tbInfo.AppendText("Event!!!!");
        }
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: you should remove calling ‍`Run` from the constructor and call it manually after the event is subscribed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Pass the event handler as a parameter on the constructor

```
public event EventHandler BluetoothDeviceDiscovered;

public BluetoothScan(MainForm mainForm, EventHandler bluetoothDeviceDiscovered)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting BluetoothScan Class");
    BluetoothDeviceDiscovered += bluetoothDeviceDiscovered
     Run();
}
```

Personally, i'm not so fun of calling method on constructor. It can be source of bugs or performance issues

[Constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming))

> In class-based object-oriented programming, a constructor
> (abbreviation: ctor) is a special type of subroutine called to create
> an object. It prepares the new object for use, often accepting
> arguments that the constructor uses to set required member variables.

You can pass eventhandler as parameter and call Run later